# JPanel does not refresh Graphics component on resize

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent

This program is supposed to draw a grid of Rectangles in a `JPanel`. I drew the grid onto the JPanel by overriding its `paintComponent` method so that every time the `JPanel` resizes, the size of the grid would change to fit the height of the `JPanel`. But when I change the size of the `JFrame`, the grid only resizes at certain intervals. Is there a better way to change the size of the grid?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.*;

class TextFrame extends JPanel
{
int numOfCells = 99;
int cellSize, xOffSet;
Rectangle2D.Float[][] square = new Rectangle2D.Float[numOfCells][numOfCells];

public TextFrame()
{
    setSize(400, 400);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics comp)
{
    Graphics2D comp2d = (Graphics2D)comp;

    cellSize = (int)getHeight()/numOfCells;
    if(getWidth()<=cellSize*numOfCells)
        cellSize = getWidth()/numOfCells;
    xOffSet = (getWidth()-(cellSize*numOfCells))/2;

    Color black = new Color(0,0,0);
    Color grey = new Color(128,128,128);
    boolean col = true;

    for(int i=0; i<square.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<square[i].length; j++)
        {
            if(col)
                comp2d.setPaint(black);
            else
                comp2d.setPaint(grey);
            col = !col;
            square[i][j] = new Rectangle2D.Float(xOffSet+j*cellSize, i*cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
            comp2d.fill(square[i][j]);
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Conway's Game Of Life");
    TextFrame life = new TextFrame();
    frame.add(life);
    frame.setSize(life.getHeight(), life.getWidth());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for intervals is integer arithmetic. Change:

```
int cellSize, xOffSet;
```

to:

```
float cellSize, xOffSet;
```

Also, change:

```
cellSize = (int)getHeight()/numOfCells;
```

to:

```
cellSize = getHeight()/(float)numOfCells;
```

Some other side notes:

- Do not change visibility of `paintComponent`, it is defined as `protected`.
- Don't forget to add `super.paintComponent(comp);` in `paintComponent()`
- Do not call `setSize()`, override panel's `getPreferredSize()` and `pack()` the frame. For example:

  ```
  public Dimension getPreferredSize(){return new Dimension(400, 400);}
  ```

  Then, add `frame.pack();` before making the frame visible.
- Try to make `paintComponent` as fast as possible for better performance and user experience. You can move some things out of it, leaving only painting logic.